# ios7 app crashes when i press home button and then resume it

Tags: ios, ios7, crash, game-center, unrecognized-selector

This is the error message i get: 
 **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString authenticationChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176769a0'
First throw call stack:
(0x30496ecb 0x3ac31ce7 0x3049a7f7 0x304990f7 0x303e8058 0x30458f01 0x303ccd69 0x30db8cc5 0x3102f43b 0x3b11ad53 0x3b11ad3f 0x3b11d6c3 0x30461641 0x3045ff0d 0x303ca729 0x303ca50b 0x353396d3 0x32d2b871 0xb8591 0x3b12fab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

I integrated game center into app and this is the code that is probably causing crash:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
        if (gameCenterAvailable) {
            NSNotificationCenter *nc =
            [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [nc addObserver:self
                   selector:@selector(authenticationChanged)
                       name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName
                     object:nil];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)authenticationChanged {
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && !userAuthenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player authenticated.");
        userAuthenticated = TRUE;

    } else if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && userAuthenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player not authenticated");
        userAuthenticated = FALSE;

    }
```

Comment: Can you also add authenticationChanged method to your question?

Comment: That's super bad code. Sorry to be harsh, but I suggest you go back to your basics.

Comment: ups, the code haven't formated well when i pasted it. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of this problem is that you never remove the observer when needed.

Add the following to your class:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

This ensure that old objects are no longer registered to receive the notification.

On a side note, don't repeat code. Your `authenticationChanged` method would be better as:

```
- (void)authenticationChanged {
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
        userAuthenticated = !userAuthenticated;
        NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player %@authenticated.", userAuthenticated ? @"" : @"not ");
    }
}
```

And be sure to use `YES` or `NO` with `BOOL` variables.